# How to call function with completion handler and parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a func `getData(completed: @escaping ()->())` that creates **alamofire** request with completion handler in one class. When alamofire ends it job, inside of this function i call `completed()` to notify that function ended its work. This func is called in other viewcontroller after button tap, but without completion handler, and then inside of this call i reload tableview with downloaded data as below.

Now i want to add to this func additional parameters to allow user modify `URL` of alamofire request, and get custom response. Parameters will be setted in other textfields. But now when i call `downloadRepositories()` i can't omit calling completion parameter.

> How can i avoid calling completion handler in it or what other
>   completion handler should i implement?

**Current alamofire request**

```
 class DataClass {

   func getData(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
   //alamofire request
   Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{
   //reponse
   completed()
   }

 }
```

**And it's implementation**

```
class OtherVC {

  var dataClass = DataClass()

  @objc func searchBtnTapped(sender: UIButton!){      
      dataclass.getData(){
          self.TableView.reloadData()
      }
  }
}
```

**What i would like to do**

```
class DataClass {

  func downloadRepositories(completed: @escaping () -> (), parameter1: String, parameter2: String) {

  let parameters: Parameters = [ "parameterA": parameter, "parameterB": parameter2 ]

  Alamofire.request(url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{
      //response
      completed()  
  }
```

**Implementation of modified func**

```
 class OtherVC {

  var dataClass = DataClass()

  @objc func searchBtnTapped(sender: UIButton!){      
      dataclass.getData(parameter1: someTextField.text, parameter2: someTextField2.text){
          self.TableView.reloadData()
      }
   }
 }
```

Of course I know that is not possible to pass parameters in func call like this, but how can do this other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this:

```
func downloadRepositories(parameter1: String, parameter2: String, completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

let parameters: Parameters = [ "parameterA": parameter, "parameterB": parameter2 ]

Alamofire.request(url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
  //response
  completed()  
}
```

Comment: how to pass a json array in this function?

Comment: What you mean by json array?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track)
If you want call func like this:

```
dataclass.getData(parameter1: someTextField.text, parameter2: someTextField2.text){
      self.TableView.reloadData()
  }
```

You just need change parameters order like this:

```
  func downloadRepositories(parameter1: String, parameter2: String, completed: @escaping () -> ())
```

If i understand right and you want use [Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html), then that's all